# How can I find the best answered c++ questions that were asked today?

Tags: discussion, support

I'd like to see all questions in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) asked today, answered and sorted by score.

Is this possible?

Comment: sorted by question score, total score of all answers, or score of highest answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
created:2014-01-20 [c++] is:question
```

[Result](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a2014-01-20%20%5bc%2b%2b%5d%20is%3aquestion)

See [this detailed description of search keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)